# Put new data to blade @foreach in Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have select tag in my page, and the options comes from the database.
When I run JS code, I recieve the new array which I need to pass except the old one (in new array I recieve new options)

```html
<select name="category_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="variant_colour">
<option selected>Select variant...</option>
    @foreach($attributes_colour_selected as $variant)
        <option value="">{{$variant->attributes_colour}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

```html
<script>
  $('#variant_model').change(function(){
    var value = $('select#variant_model').val();
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    });
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "showVariantModel",
      data: {value:value},
      success: function(data){
      var attr = 'I don't know what to pass here';
      
      $('#variant_colour:last').append(attr);

      }
    })

  });
</script>
```

Can you suggest the simpliest way to change foreach arguments.
New variable comes from Controller. 
When I write the string like this:

```html
<script>
var attr = '@foreach($attributes_colour_selected as $variant)'+
          'blablabla'+
          '@endforeach';
</script>
```

Nothing works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply do a `foreach` since you haven't explained what type of array you are returning, so i'll simply assume it to be a `{key: value}` type array, so in you success function

```
success: function(response){
  let select = document.querySelector('#variant_colour')
  select.innerHTML = '' //if you want to remove previous options 
  response.forEach((op)=>{
    select.innerHTML += `<option value=${op.id}>${op.value}</option>`
 })
}
```

Also, you'll need to provide some value in your option value attribute in your blade

```
<option value="{{ $variant->id }}">{{$variant->attributes_colour}}</option> //set some value example id
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
You forgot to put ) in the end: </option>`  } ) }

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use js to loop the data. I do not know how is the structure that returns the ajax call, but you can try something like this with jquery:

```
<script>
  $('#variant_model').change(function(){
    var value = $('select#variant_model').val();
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
    });
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url: "showVariantModel",
      data: {value:value},
      success: function(data){
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $('#variant_colour').append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value + "</option>");
        });
      }
    })

  });
</script>
```